# how to condense loops or make them fewer in C++

Tags: c++

I had a CS question that wants me to check for the number of palindromes found inside a single array of 6 cells. i was able to solve it by using many for loops, 7 of them to be exact, and I'm trying to find a way to make the code tidier by reducing the number of loops because they all do similar things with minor differences but i wasn't able to put a finger on the best idea to reduce them.

this my code:

```
int main()
{
    int size = 6;
    int array[size];
    int palCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> array[i];
    }

    bool isPal = true;

    int size2 = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        int currentNum = array[i];
        int numAfter = array[i + 1];

        int arrToCheck[] = {currentNum, numAfter};
        isPal = checkPalindrom(arrToCheck, size2);

        if (isPal)
        {
            palCount++;
        }
    }

    int size3 = 3;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        int currentNum = array[i];
        int numAfter = array[i + 1];
        int numAfter2 = array[i + 2];

        int arrToCheck[] = {currentNum, numAfter, numAfter2};
        isPal = checkPalindrom(arrToCheck, size3);

        if (isPal)
        {
            palCount++;
        }
    }

    int size4 = 4;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        int currentNum = array[i];
        int numAfter = array[i + 1];
        int numAfter2 = array[i + 2];
        int numAfter3 = array[i + 3];

        int arrToCheck[] = {currentNum, numAfter, numAfter2, numAfter3};
        isPal = checkPalindrom(arrToCheck, size4);

        if (isPal)
        {
            palCount++;
        }
    }

    int size5 = 5;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        int currentNum = array[i];
        int numAfter = array[i + 1];
        int numAfter2 = array[i + 2];
        int numAfter3 = array[i + 3];
        int numAfter4 = array[i + 4];

        int arrToCheck[] = {currentNum, numAfter, numAfter2, numAfter3, numAfter4};
        isPal = checkPalindrom(arrToCheck, size5);

        if (isPal)
        {
            palCount++;
        }
    }

    //================================================================

    for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        int currentNum = array[i];
        int numAfter = array[i + 1];

        int arrToCheck[] = {currentNum, numAfter};
        isPal = checkPalindrom(arrToCheck, size2);

        if (isPal)
        {
            palCount++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        int currentNum = array[i];
        int numAfter = array[i + 1];
        int numAfter2 = array[i + 2];

        int arrToCheck[] = {currentNum, numAfter, numAfter2};
        isPal = checkPalindrom(arrToCheck, size3);

        if (isPal)
        {
            palCount++;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        int currentNum = array[i];
        int numAfter = array[i + 1];
        int numAfter2 = array[i + 2];
        int numAfter3 = array[i + 3];

        int arrToCheck[] = {currentNum, numAfter, numAfter2, numAfter3};
        isPal = checkPalindrom(arrToCheck, size4);

        if (isPal)
        {
            palCount++;
        }
    }

    cout << palCount - 1 << endl;
}
```

in case anyone wants to try the code, this is the code of the function that checks for palindromes:

```
bool checkPalindrom(int arr[], int sizeOfArray)
{
    int size = sizeOfArray;
    bool pal = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] != arr[size - 1 - i])
        {
            pal = false;
        }
    }
    return pal;
}
```

the differences between each loop that it starts with 2 elemts then 3 then 4... the arrayToCheck variable is the one that's changing between each loop and also the variable size.

im open to any ideas on how to reduce the number of loops while keeping the same functionality.thanks.

expected:

```
input: 1 1 1 1 1 1
output: 15
```

```
input: 1 2 2 1 5 5
output: 3
```

Comment: Unrelated. Think on the range of `i` in `for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)` and the valid bounds of `array[i]`, `array[i + 1]`, `array[i + 2]`, and ` array[i + 3]`.

Comment: Unrelated: Save a few CPU cycles: in `checkPalindrom` either replace `pal = false;` with `return false;` or follow it with `break;`. No point checking the rest of the the array after you know it's not a palindrome.

Comment: Note: if your code works, but you wish to improve it, you may wish to ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, most of the loops are doing really similar thing, so let look at one of them and see what it is doing:

```cpp
int size4 = 4;
for (int i = 2; i <= 6; i++)
{
    int currentNum = array[i];
    int numAfter = array[i + 1];
    int numAfter2 = array[i + 2];
    int numAfter3 = array[i + 3];

    int arrToCheck[] = {currentNum, numAfter, numAfter2, numAfter3};
    isPal = checkPalindrom(arrToCheck, size4);

    if (isPal)
    {
        palCount++;
    }
}
```

- First, there is a bound issue. When `i` is greater than 2, you will go `i + 3` is 6, which will create a bound issue when you trying to access that index from `array`.
- Second, we don't need to create this `arrToCheck`. The `checkPalindrom` function simply want a pointer and a size, so we can just pass `array + i` to it.

And now we can simplify this part like:

```cpp
for (int i = 2; i < 3; ++i) {
    isPal = checkPalindrom(array + i, size4);
    if (isPal)
    {
        ++palCount;
    }
}
```

---

Now if we do the same thing with all the other loops, we will realize, the only difference between them now is the condition of the for loop, and the `sizeX` in there are different. We are getting something like:

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i < 5; ++i) { ... size2 ... }
for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i) { ... size3 ... }
for (int i = 1; i < 3; ++i) { ... size4 ... }
for (int i = 1; i < 2; ++i) { ... size5 ... }

for (int i = 2; i < 5; ++i) { ... size2 ... }
for (int i = 2; i < 4; ++i) { ... size3 ... }
for (int i = 2; i < 3; ++i) { ... size4 ... }
```

I hope you can see the pattern now. The beginning is from 1 to 2, the end is from 5(size of original array - 1) to beginning + 1, and the `sizeX` is size of original array - end + 1. With these information, you can get a 2d for loop like:

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (int j = size - 1; j > i; --j) {
        ... size - j + 1 ...
    }
}
```

---

Now, there is one major bug with your solution(become much easier to spot when we don't need look at 100 lines of repetitive code), remember what `i` and `j` are? They are basically the numbers we used with `checkPalindrom` function:

```cpp
checkPalindrom(array + i, j)
```

Why exactly does `i` only range between 1 and 2? Shouldn't we start the check with an array that begins from the first number, and only end after we have less than 2 numbers? So we really should have changed the outer loop to loop from `0` to `5`.

Comment: i just have a question regarding the second for loop, i didn't understand where exactly to write size-j+1, and is it supposed to be inside every single loop of them or is it a replacement for all the loops

Comment: @Milad The nested for loop is to replace all for loops. And `size-j+1` should be used in place where you used to have `size2`, `size3`, and etc.

Answer (score -1):

First thing to notice, you're essentially copying the array members when you call `checkPalindrom()`. That's unnecessary: you can simply call it as `checkPalindrom(array + i, size_i);`. Then your code is reduced to essentially do the same loop multiple times. You still need to fix array boundary errors (as the original code over-indexed the array).

So the loop body is:

```
auto checker = [&](int size_i, int i_min, int i_max) {
    for (int i = i_min; i <= i_max && i + size_i <= size; i++)
    {
        isPal = checkPalindrom(array + i, size_i);

        if (isPal)
        {
            palCount++;
        }
    }
```

Then you loop it for the necessary range:

```
for (int i_min = 1; i_min <= 2; ++i_min) {
  for (int size_i = 2; size_i + i_min < size; ++size_i) {
    checker(i_min, 6, size_i);
  }
}
```

Also, it's suggested to change sizes and offsets to `size_t`.